# S3 to RDS file management system

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rds

I'm new to AWS and have a feasibility question for a file management system I'm trying to build. I would like to set up a system where people will use the Amazon S3 browser and drop either a csv or excel file into their specific bucket. Then I would like to automate the process of taking that csv/excel file and inserting that into a table within RDS. Now this is assuming that the table has already been built and those excel/csv file will always be formatted the same and will be in the same exact place every single time. Is it possible to automate this process or at least get it to point where very minimal human interference is needed. I'm new to AWS so I'm not exactly sure of the limits of S3 to RDS. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely possible. AWS supports notifications from S3 to SNS, which can be forwarded automatically to SQS: http://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/s3-event-notification/

S3 can also send notifications to [AWS Lambda](http://aws.amazon.com/lambda/) to run your own code directly.

Comment: I think the Lambda route would be ideal. Simply write a small JavaScript event handler, parsing source CSV files when they are deposited into S3 and writing them as records to the database. One way to kickstart this might be to look at https://github.com/ashiina/aws-lambda-rds-sample.